# How to make rownames first column and replace a given cell with a value in a list of data frames?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of roughly 200 datasets where each data set looks like:

```
Year     2010  2011 2012 2013 2014
Womenpct 0.6   0.8  0.7  0.6  0.7
Menpct   0.4   0.2  0.3  0.4  0.3
```

What I want to achieve is to first replace the rownames in each dataset to

```
Year   2010  2011 2012 2013 2014
Women  0.6   0.8  0.7  0.6  0.7
Men    0.4   0.2  0.3  0.4  0.3
```

Data:

```
   df <- list(`1` = structure(c("2010", "0.5388350", "0.4611650", "2011", 
"0.5360517", "0.4639483", "2012", "0.5460852", "0.4539148", "2013", 
"0.5401961", "0.4598039", "2014", "0.5475490", "0.4524510"), .Dim = c(3L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Year", "Womenpct", "Menpct"), NULL)), 
`2` = structure(c("2010", "0.5388350", "0.4611650", "2011", 
"0.5360517", "0.4639483", "2012", "0.5460852", "0.4539148", 
"2013", "0.5401961", "0.4598039", "2014", "0.5475490", "0.4524510"
), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Year", "Womenpct", 
"Menpct"), NULL)))
```

After this I'm trying to make the rownames the first column, and want all datasets have the following structure

```
Year          2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
Women Women   0.6  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.7
Men   Men     0.4  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.3
```

For the rownames I've tried using `lapply` to change them

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) rownames(x)[1] <- "Women")
```

But this only returns a single character in each data frame.

To insert a column I've also tried to use `lapply`

```
 lapply(df, function(x) add_column(x, Gender = "", .before = 1))
```

Which seems to convert my data frames into new lists instead.

Is there some way I can get R to apply the desired functions for all data frames in my list?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post `dput(df[[1]])` ? those look like column already and maybe you want to add new rownames instead.

Comment: @RonakShah                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                            list(`1` = structure(c("2010", "0.5388350", "0.4611650", 
"2011", "0.5360517", "0.4639483", "2012", "0.5460852", "0.4539148", 
"2013", "0.5401961", "0.4598039", "2014", "0.5475490", "0.4524510"), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Year", "Womenpct", "Menpct"), NULL)))

Comment: Your `dput` returns a matrix. Are you interested in using  a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgoing apply functions, this should do what you want:

```
for (i in seq_along(table.list)) {
  df <- table.list[[i]]
  rownames(df)[-1] <- c("Women", "Men")
  df <- cbind(c("", rownames(df)[-1]), df)
  table.list[[i]] <- df
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `dput` it looks like you have list of matrices with column names as first row. We can do

```
lapply(df, function(x) {
    #Convert matrix to dataframe
    temp <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    #Remove pct from rownames
    rownames(temp) <- sub("pct$", "", rownames(temp))
    #Add rownames as new column
    temp$Year <- rownames(temp)
    #Assign first row as column names
    names(temp) <- temp[1, ]
    #Remove first row
    temp[-1, ]
})

#$`1`
#           2010      2011      2012      2013      2014  Year
#Women 0.5388350 0.5360517 0.5460852 0.5401961 0.5475490 Women
#Men   0.4611650 0.4639483 0.4539148 0.4598039 0.4524510   Men

#$`2`
#           2010      2011      2012      2013      2014  Year
#Women 0.5388350 0.5360517 0.5460852 0.5401961 0.5475490 Women
#Men   0.4611650 0.4639483 0.4539148 0.4598039 0.4524510   Men
```

**data**

```
df <- list(`1` = structure(c("2010", "0.5388350", "0.4611650", "2011", 
"0.5360517", "0.4639483", "2012", "0.5460852", "0.4539148", "2013", 
"0.5401961", "0.4598039", "2014", "0.5475490", "0.4524510"), .Dim = c(3L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Year", "Womenpct", "Menpct"), NULL)), 
`2` = structure(c("2010", "0.5388350", "0.4611650", "2011", 
"0.5360517", "0.4639483", "2012", "0.5460852", "0.4539148", 
"2013", "0.5401961", "0.4598039", "2014", "0.5475490", "0.4524510"
), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Year", "Womenpct", 
"Menpct"), NULL)))
```